# Setting a custom allocator for strings

Tags: c++, string, allocator

I know I can set a custom allocator for vectors using the syntax `vector<T, Alloc>`. Is there a way I can do the same for strings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. All string classes come from the class template `basic_string`, declared as such:

```
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
            class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string;
```

For example, `std::string` is just `typedef basic_string<char> string;`.

The third template parameter is the allocator, so you can do something like:

```
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, my_allocator<char> > my_string;
```

Comment: Note: my_allocator need not be a template.